# Docker: cannot link containers in --net=host mode

Tags: docker, couchbase

I have a Couchbase server container named `db` launched with `--net=host` option which exposes port 11210, and now I have to link another container to it. 
If I use the `--link` option while running my new container, that is type:

```
docker run -d -P --name my_name --link db:db my_image
```

I get:

> Error response from daemon: Conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links. This would result in undefined behavior.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

"Linking" containers doesn't make any sense when using `--net=host`.  When you link containers, Docker creates entries in `/etc/hosts` so that the containers can connect to each other by name, but when using `--net=host` your containers do not have unique addresses.  They are sharing the host network environment.

You can just use `localhost` to access services running in either container, or any valid address on your host (assuming that your service is configured to listen on all available addresses).